# enum causes multiply defined error while typedef enum doesnt

Tags: c, enums, typedef

Im compliling C code.

Say i have header file, A.h which contains an enum.
I include this file in 2 c files - B.c and C.c

B.c:

```
#include A.h
//....other code...
```

C.c

```
#include A.h
//....other code...
```

When A.h contains an enum:

A.h

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

enum my_enum {

  //...enum content...

} my_enum;

//...other code...

#endif
```

when defined like this, i get a 'symbol "my_enum" multiply defined' error from the compiler, which is understandable- since i defined the enum in the header file.

However, this does not happen when i typedef the enum-

A.h

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

typedef enum my_enum {

  //...enum content...

} my_enum;

//...other code...

#endif
```

This of course happens regardless of what the code is in the .c files (other than including A.h)

What is the reasoning behind this?
Why is it not a multiple definition when i typedef the enum?

Answer (score 4):

```
enum my_enum {

  //...enum content...

} my_enum;
```

`my_enum` here is not a type, but a variable of type `enum my_enum`. Including this in a header leads to multiple definition of the variable `my_enum`.

```
typedef enum my_enum {

  //...enum content...

} my_enum;
```

`my_enum` here is a type, not a variable. It's a type the same as `enum my_enum`. That's the function of `typedef`.

Answer (score 1):

In C there are different **name spaces**.
We have this rules of "interference" (or not) of identifiers:

- Identifiers in different **scopes** are not in conflct.
- Identifiers in the same **scope**, but belonging to different **name spaces** are not in conflict.

These **name spaces** are:

1. Ordinary identifiers (designating objects, functions, `typedef` names and enumeration constants).
2. `enum`, `struct`, `union` tags.
3. `struct/union` members.
4. Labels (used with `goto`).

Thus, for example, since `typedef` names, `enum` tagss, `struct` members and labels are all in different **name spaces**, the following code has no any conflicts:

```
  int main(void)   // "x" is always in diffrent name spaces and/or scopes
  {
       typedef struct { struct { float x; } x; }  x;
       enum x { zero = 0 } value = zero;

       x:    // Label

      if (value != 0)
           goto x;

      { // This block is another scope

          typedef enum x { one = 1 } x;
          x w = one;
      }
  }
```

For reference, see **Section 6.2.3** of C standard document: [Standard C99, TC3](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

When you use typedef it will treat my_enum as just an alias of enum.

i.e. in that case my_enum behaves as a type and not a variable.

If you do not use typedef it will multiple declaration..